# How to use new XAMPP dashboard?

Tags: xampp

I guess the question says it all. I downloaded the newest version of XAMPP, and instead of taking me to a configuration page, it takes me to localserver/dashboard. How do I get to security settings, etc?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to look over: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We answer questions related to specific programming problems, not applications (try over at SuperUser or the app's support directly).

Comment: Wait, someone actually up-voted this?